# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot some diagrams in RStudio

```
  while(1+window+n <= length(data[,1]))
{

  datalistB<-datalist[n:(n+window-1)]
...
    par(mfrow = c(i+1, 1))
    plot(datalistB, type="l")
    for(i in seq_along(loop.vec)) {
        plot( subsignals[[i]], type="l")
    }

n<-n+10
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

but If I have more than four plots, I getting this error: [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/troubleshooting/problem-with-plots-or-graphics-device) said that I should increase the size of the plots pane. I did it, but doesn't help me.

Is there another solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `par(mai=...)` and `par(mar=...)` to reduce the margin size around your plots. You should also consider using `lattice` or `ggplot2` that were designed for this use case of plotting multiple subplots on the same frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
par(mfcol=c(12,12), oma=c(1,1,0,0), mar=c(1,1,1,0), tcl=-0.1, mgp=c(0,0,0))
    plot(datalistB,type="l")
      for(i in seq_along(loop.vec))
      {
        plot( subsignals[[i]],type="l")
      }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but sometimes I lost this Plot `plot(datalistB,type="l")` My plots pane updated every 0.5 seconds and some times I lost the first plot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because I can't see your data, but the problem may arise because you're plotting a list. Try this

```
as.numeric(unlist(datalistB)) -> datalistB
```

before plotting.